# c++ preprocessor value truncated in cout

Tags: c++

I have the following in source code.

```
#define VAR 3.0
```

but when I try to print it out,

```
cout << VAR;
```

I get the value

```
 3
```

The same thing happens when I pass a preprocessor flag -DVAR. I have checked output with

```
g++ -E -P
```

and the correct value is being replaced by the preprocessor but the executable output is being truncated.

Comment: It's not being truncated, it's being rounded. If you want to output it as a _string_, define it as one.

Comment: What makes you think it has anything to do with the preprocessor?

Comment: And it's not even a type conversion. cout just tries to be smart and sees that the value doesn't have any fractions so prints out the integer part. If it was `#define VAR 3.1415926535` the output would be `3.14159`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It's not being rounded in my opinion. See my comment, a PI is printed out to certain fixed point fractions.

Comment: @CsabaToth You're right, it's better to say that streams by default output as few decimals as possible, thus `.0` is not needed.

Comment: It's not the first time I see many down votes for a reasonable (though novice) question without a single explaining comment. What's wrong with you people?

Comment: @user2645859 you should accept the answer or ask if something isn't clear

Answer (score 5):

you can try to do `cout << 3.0;` and also get the output 3
it's not the preprocessor that does it, it's just that you try to output a float and this is how float are printed

if you'll define:

```
#define VAR "3.0"
```

you'll get the wanted output